# How would I click on a piece of text on a website in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm attempting to click on some shown text on a website in JS. The shown text is "Supreme®/Vanson Leathers® Worn Leather Jacket".
My code is:

```
const readline = require('readline-sync');
const {exec} = require("child_process")


function cmdCommand(cmd){
    exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }
        
        console.log(`Utilizing the quantum: ${stdout}`);    
    });
}

const reader = require("readline-sync"); 
let answer = reader.question("1,2,3,4,5,or 6?: ");

answer === "1"? cmdCommand("start chrome https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/jackets",
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("Supreme®/Vanson Leathers® Worn Leather Jacket").click();
  }
  





):""
```

I'm using readline-sync to have an array of options to choose from, with option 1 launching the website, but I do not know how to click on the text.

Comment: There is no getElementByText in DOM

Comment: We need more context. There is no native JavaScript function `cmdCommand`, nor native DOM method `document.getElementByText`.

Comment: I edited it with more code, sorry.

Comment: That dosnt work, your mixing server&client side code. You just starting chrome from node. you have no access to the dom in chrome from node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome doesn't provide an API that lets you run it with `start` and then remote control it.

So ditch that.

Pick a library that lets you remote control a browser, such as [CasperJS](https://www.casperjs.org/) or [Selenium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver) and get to grips with its API instead.